# C# How to parse non-standard xml

Tags: c#, parsing

I have many long documents that need to be parsed. The document format is like XML but not actually xml.

Here's an example:

```
<DOC>
    <TEXT>it's the content P&G</TEXT>
</DOC> 
<DOC>
    <TEXT>it's antoher</TEXT>
</DOC>
```

Note that there are mutiple root tags - `<DOC>`, and the entity `&` should be `&amp;` in xml.

Thus, the above file is not a standard xml.

Can I use the `XmlDocument` to parse the file, or should I write my own parser?

Comment: Would a replace of & with &amp;, and wrapping the whole string with <xml> ... </xml> be enough? Or is there more?

Comment: Since it's not XML you'll not be able to use an XML parser. You'll want to decide what it really is, and then use a parser for that thing.

Comment: I'm going to be brutal and remove the "XML" tag, since this is a question about how to parse some language that isn't XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are saying is somewhat incorrect - that this is "not standard XML". The document is **not** XML. Period.

You *cannot* use `XmlDocument` or any other XML parser to parse it as a complete document.

You need to ensure that you have valid XML before you try to parse it using an XML parser.

So - in this case, either warp the document in a root element or break it out to several documents. In either case, you need to ensure that the special characters are encoded correctly (quotes, ampersands etc...).

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17742853/1583) by oakio gets you part way by treating the document as an XML fragment, but this still doesn't help with invalid content such as unescaped ampersands.

Answer (score 2):

As @Oded says, this isn't an XML document - just some text.

However with some pre-parsing you might be able to convert it:

Wrap the whole thing in a new root node:

```
<DOCS>
    <DOC>
        <TEXT>it's the content P&G</TEXT>
    </DOC> 
    <DOC>
        <TEXT>it's antoher</TEXT>
    </DOC>
<DOCS>
```

And search for the disallowed chars and replace with their entities (eg `&apos;` and `&amp;`).

As pointed out in the comments, you should replace `&` first to avoid double encoding (ie ending up with `&apos;amp;`)

You might have to do this via string manipulation though, depending on where you're getting the data from.

Comment: Only issue with the string replace is double encoding (in particular when replacing `&` with `&amp;`, which is why it should be the _first_ replacement).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you should set `XmlReaderSettings.ConformanceLevel`:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings()
{
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
};
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings))
{
    //TODO: read here
}
```

More: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.conformancelevel.aspx)